# "reset date value in Javascript"?

Tags: javascript

1. How to "reset date value in Javascript" everytime the div in html is clicked? I am trying to make a basic delivery calculation date based from today's date, for example, 3 days delivery date from today(let say today is 5 November 2011). When user click on it, it must show the delivery date will be on Tuesday 8 November 2011, but when user click on it again, the second time, today's date has changed to be based on 8 November 2011 instead of 5. How to reset/clear the "Today" variable to be based on today's date?
2. How to display day in Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, and so on instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7?

My current code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Today = new Date();
    var NumDelivery = 0;

    function Calculate() {
        var days = Today.getDay();
        var dd = Today.getDate();
        var mm = Today.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = Today.getFullYear();
        var FormattedDate = days + ',' + dd + '-'+ mm + '-'+ y;
        Today.setDate(Today.getDate() + NumDelivery); 
        $('#DateDelivery').text(FormattedDate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm, how about simply use `NewDate = new Date()` and then instead of `Today.setDate(...)` use `NewDate.setDate(...)`

As for day names you can use an array like this :

```
var d = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
dayName =  d[NewDate.getDay()];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the var Today = new Date() into the function Calculate

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var NumDelivery = 0;
var DAYS_OF_WEEK = [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thr', 'Fri', 'Sat' ];

function Calculate() {
    var Today = new Date();
    var days = Today.getDay();
    var dd = Today.getDate();
    var mm = Today.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = Today.getFullYear();
    var FormattedDate = DAYS_OF_WEEK[days] + ',' + dd + '-'+ mm + '-'+ y;
    Today.setDate(Today.getDate() + NumDelivery); 
    $('#DateDelivery').text(FormattedDate);
}
```

I displayed the day of week name using an array.

Comment: The preferred structure for this type of data is an enum. The syntax is 
namespace.daysEnum = {
    Sun:0,Mon:1,Tue:2,Wed:3,Thr:4,01
}

// later on

if(currentColor == my.namespace.ColorEnum.RED) {
   // whatever
}

Comment: @SinthiaV, he's going the other direction: from index to name, not name to index.

Comment: I have tried the given example above. The result will be 5 November 2011 every time I click, not 8 November. But thanks for the Days of Weeks.

Comment: Try adding after var Today = new Date(); a line that says Today.setDate(Today.getDate()+3);

Comment: The preferred structure for this type of data is an enum. The syntax is 
daysOfWeek.daysEnum = {Sun:0,Mon:1,Tue:2,Wed:3,Thr:4,Fri:5,Sat:6}
// later on
daysOfWeek.Fri //yields 5

Comment: @Scott A: I was in the middle of commenting when my cat broke my coffee cup FULL of course. Please disregard the nonsense.

Comment: @SinthiaV: it's still the wrong way round. He want to go from, for example, 5 to "Friday", not Friday to 5.

Comment: @SinthiaV: that one has been sorted, the problems now are when I click on some elements on the form, the first click, the date show 5 November 2011 instead of 8 November ON_THE_FIRST_CLICK. Then I have to click on the same element again, then the date will be correct, 8 November. And the other one, I was asking is there any Javascript command to clear the date value like in textbox ""?

Comment: I don't think your question is clear. What date value are you trying to clear?